# I have used localStorage but its not working,whenever i refresh the page its cleaned out

Tags: jquery

there is a bookmark button whose id is "bkmrk",on click on it it will save the value from input field in a 'name' key and then it will add the name in an unordered list,whose id is 'ul_bkmrk'. It is attaching the name into my unoredered list but it is not showing the result after i refresh my page.

```
$("#bkmrk").click(function() {
        if(localStorage) {
          localStorage.setItem("name",$("#repo_name").val());
        }
        else {
          console.log("local storage is not supported!!");
        }
        $("#ul_bkmrk").append("<li>"+localStorage.getItem("name")+"</li>");
      });
```

Comment: Are you using _private browsing_, _incognito_?

Comment: provide the code of list showing

Comment: well, it works. It is not this piece of code that is the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/wkjj4wms/